# Pyinstaller no module named 'pyfiglet.fonts ' pyinstaller '

Tags: python, selenium, pyinstaller

Hey i want to export my Python Selenium Projekt with Pyinstaller but every time when im trying to do this it wotrks but when i start the exe file i became this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'pyfiglet.fonts'
```

to start pyinstaller i used this command:

```
pyinstaller --onefile SickoAIO.py
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a little more information, it's hard to tell what's wrong. However, I'm going to assume some things you haven't stated and provide some ideas:

1. Assuming SickoAIO.py works fine before you try to use pyinstaller, sometimes if in your Python code you only imported the more general module:

```
import pyfiglet
```

but need to use pyfiglet.fonts, a "hack" for it to work in pyinstaller could be to make the import more specific:

```
import pyfiglet.fonts
```

I've not used pyfiglet, but this hack worked for me with the numpy module, for example.

2. Another thing that has helped me troubleshoot a similar issue with numpy, scipy, etc. is updating the versions of the module and/or pyinstaller
3. It's possible you may need to use hooks, especially since it seems like pyfiglet may not play well with pyinstaller. This is explained specifically for pyfiglet here:
   https://hugomartins.io/essays/2019/06/pyinstaller-pyfiglet-trouble/
   I didn't try it, and it looks like you may need to click on more links in that webpage as well as learn more about how hooks work in pyinstaller (https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/hooks.html?highlight=hook) to understand the full issue.